# How to save favorite routes in constantly changing bus schedules

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm designing a bus scheduling app for WP8..

Right now I have a parser which downloads the data from bus company's website and saves it to the server as JSON where it can be downloaded and deserialized by WP8 app.

How can I allow users to save their favorite routes when the schedules changes every few weeks ? Or maybe there's more correct or more effective way to store whole schedules ?

Comment: Why do the bus schedules change every week? that seems rather unusual to me.

Comment: Do buses operate set routes that don't change and have unique identifiers (eg the 37 goes from Northwich to Crewe), but the times do change?

Comment: When a user saves there favourite route, lets say the number 22 bus that arrives at 8am this week. Next week the number 22 bus's schedule changes to arrive at 9am for that week, what do you want to happen to the users saved route? Update the time from 8am to 9am or have them look up the route again and resave it?

Comment: @pcwizz yes, but there's few variants of each route eg 37 from Northwich to Crewe and another 37 from Northwich to .. a few stops after or before Crewe :)

my point is that my parser is replacing the json and assigning new ids every time it runs. it's fine when nothing's changed and ids stay the same.. but when some route is missing - ids won't match. I'm looking for the way to uniquely identify every route so I can save only ID in favorites.

Comment: Can a route is just a list of stops independant of time operated and a route is operated at the times scrapped from the website? Then you can just match the list of stops -tip hasing the list is going to be quicker than looping through checking each stop in the list-.